# Windows server time going back to past due to time synchronization with the hardware clock

Tags: windows-server-2016, hardware, time, time-synchronization, clock-synchronization

For two months we are facing issue on our Windows Server 2016 server every 10 days.

Server time is going back by one hour with the below message in event log.

`The system time has changed to ‎2023‎-‎12‎-‎27T07:34:29.500000000Z from ‎2023‎-‎12‎-‎27T08:34:38.153992100Z. Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock.`

The time corrects without intervention after two hours.

`The system time has changed to ‎2023‎-‎12‎-‎27T09:34:29.500000000Z from ‎2023‎-‎12‎-‎27T08:34:29.508436400Z. Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock.`

'Set Time Automatically' is off in 'Date & Time settings'. StartUp type of Windows Time service is  Manual (Trigger) and is not running.

This is a workgroup server, not joined to a domain.
We don't have access to the server Hardware since it is managed by a different vendor.

How can we avoid the system time being synchronized with the hardware clock?

Comment: You ask the wrong question. Why is your hardware clock running out of sync? Defective? Is that isolated to the clock? I would go to the core, not try to use a painkiller instead of treating the wound.

Comment: So this this above event happened at 2023‎-‎12‎-‎27T09:34:29 UTC?

Comment: How do you go on and on about a system synchronizing with hardware,  *and not provide the type of hardware*?

Comment: "We don't have access to the server Hardware since it is managed by a different vendor." - so, seriously, open a ticket, their hardware management is wrong. Likely they override the system time and have the wrong timezone set or something. Bark the right tree - hardware issue.

Comment: I dont understand this. Please see the Logged time.                                                 
The system time has changed to ‎2023‎-‎12‎-‎27T07:34:29.500000000Z from ‎2023‎-‎12‎-‎27T08:34:38.153992100Z.
Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock. Logged Time: 12/27/2023 11:34:29 AM

Comment: System time is in Abu Dhabi timezone which is UTC+4. Logged time is in UTC+4.

Comment: ok, so it's not a timezone problem on your OS install,   contact the hardware provider for assistance.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response. We have already contacted the Hardware provide & they need downtime to check the issue which we cannot afford at this point of time. Kindly suggest if there is a way to disable the synchronization with the hardware clock.